# Interpolation inequality for fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-spaces

In Theorem 5.2 of the book

*Robert A. Adams and John J. F. Fournier*, MR 2424078 [**Sobolev spaces**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2424078), ISBN: 0-12-044143-8.

is stated that, for any integers $0 \leq j \leq m$ and $u \in W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ (under suitable assumptions on $\Omega$), the following interpolation inequality holds
$$
\|u\|_{W^{j,p}} \lesssim \|u\|^{j/m}_{W^{m,p}} \cdot \|u\|_{L^p}^{(m-j)/m}.
$$

Is there an analogous result for Sobolev spaces of *fractional* order? (I am particularly interested in the case $p=2$).

Comment: Inequalities like this are pretty much the point of interpolation spaces. There are whole books about the subject.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you please suggest me a good reference?